To Address auto populating with previous email address in case object
Requirement :
I have requirement to create a quick action button on standard case object to send email.
I need to auto-populate To Address with the default email address(Pre-defined value).
Work I have done:

I have created new object specific action Send Email and added pre-defined value To Address with default email id.
I have also created a custom quick action which invokes headerless LWC component, in the invoke method I am redirecting to standard sendemail quickaction component.


@api invoke() {
    var pageRef = {
        type: "standard__quickAction",
        attributes: {
            apiName: "Case.SendEmail",
        },
        state: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            defaultFieldValues: encodeDefaultFieldValues({
                ToAddress: predefinedemailaddress
                
            }),
        },
    };

    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageRef);
}


Problem:
The value in ToAddress field is populating the predefined email address only on the initial email sent from the case. but, when I am trying to send a new email from same case it is bringing the previous email's ToAddress in both the cases.
As, per my business requirement I don't want previous email's ToAddress to be populated in my ToAddress field when I am  trying to send new email second time from case(Want only Predefined email address in ToAddress field)
Please let me know any workaround for this ?
Thanks in advance

Apologies, if I'm overlooking something, but where do you get predefinedemailaddress from? How is the variable initialized? When speaking of "the default email address", are you referring to the ContactEmail of the Case? Why is your expectation that the email changes between two different send actions?

predefinedemailaddress will come from label, as per client requirement when ever we click on quick action button email(from custom label in LWC) should be auto populated in TO Address field on the case object. I don't want ContactEmail of the case because it will different for each case.
